# The Input Text keyword of Robot Framework does not work

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Below is the code that I have written:

```
    open browser  https://www.amazon.com  chrome
    maximize browser window
    sleep  3s
    input text  id=twotabsearchtextbox  Ferrari 458
    click button  xpath=//div[@class='nav-search-submit nav-sprite']/input[@class='nav-input']
```

When executed I am getting the below error message:

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Please note that the Chrome Driver and the chrome browser used is the latest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTJLv.png)

Answer (score 5):

You have the incorrect version of chromedriver installed. Take a look at this part of the error message:

```
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
```

chromedriver 2.33 is very old, and only supports very old versions of chrome. According to the [chromedriver download page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), version 79.x of chrome requires version 79.x version of chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

When i run your code making use of chrome on mac os with the below versions listed for chrome-driver , the code simply works, without any issues. I suspect, there might be some issue with your chromedriver, can you please verify the chrome-driver which you are making use of is the same as the one mentioned below?

```
(rf0) 06:22 PM##~::>/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
Google Chrome 79.0.3945.79
(rf0) 06:23 PM##~::>chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877})
```

Below code

```
*** Settings ***
Library SeleniumLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
SAMPLE
        Open browser  https://www.amazon.com  chrome
        maximize browser window
        sleep  3s
        input text  id=twotabsearchtextbox  Ferrari 458
        click button  xpath=//div[@class='nav-search-submit nav-sprite']/input[@class='nav-input']
```

**Output**

```
(rf0) 06:21 PM##~::>robot s.robot
==============================================================================
S
==============================================================================
SAMPLE                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S                                                                     | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /Users/apachemain/output.xml
Log:     /Users/apachemain/log.html
Report:  /Users/apachemain/report.html
```